# Visual Studio 2013 - Code Lens - What happened to my references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Code lens references has stopped working since I installed ReSharper. I use Resharper 8.

All I get now is -references:

[image: CodeLens]

I've tried disabling and re-enabling code lens, but it makes no difference. Any other similar questions responses here on SO have made no difference either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Look here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809868/codelens-not-displaying-references), this helped in my case.
Seems to happen, for example, in case of cross-referenced projects in your solution.

Comment: I have a couple of solutions which have multiple (up to 10) projects, both of which show "-references", none of which have cross project references. However if I create a new console app, the references work fine.

Comment: I deleted a reference to log4net in a project which didn't use it and since restarting VS, the references are now working! Bizarre!

Comment: Glad to be helpful :D